# How does JavaScript's Bit-wise operation deals with NOT (~) operation?

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

Executing the following lines of code in JavaScript always produce unexpected result, which I do not have any clue with.
This is how I perform a NOT (invert) operation:

**2** = `0010`

**(~ 2)** = `1101`, which is `13` in decimal. But performing this exact same operation in JavaScript outputs the value `-3`. Can anyone explain why so?

```
<body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ~ 2;
    </script>
    </body>
```

**Result:** `-3`

Comment: Because JS uses 32 bit signed integers instead of 4 bit unsigned integers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript uses [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation for integer values. It also performs all bitwise operations on signed, 32-bit integers (converting arguments as necessary). So the expression `~2` does not result in `1101`; instead it is

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1101
```

which happens to be the two's complement representation of -3. (The leftmost bit being 1 indicates a negative number.)

Consult [the docs on bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) for more info.

P.S. If you really want a result of 13, you can mask out all but the lower four bits: `((~2) & 0xF)`.

Answer (score 0):

It is a unary operator that takes the expression to its right performs this small algorithm on it (where N is the expression to the right of the tilde): **-(N+1)**

For example ~2 produces -3

Comment: Actually a nice analogy, but you should name it as such and not make it seem that this is the actual operation / algorithm being performed - as it doesn't explain e.g. why it only works for N < 2**31 and that it truncates floating point numbers.